# Word 2007 Script random font generator

Tags: ms-word

Would any one know or be able to help me get this to work with Word 2007. 
This is a code snippet that is supposed to set styles randomly.

```
//Create instance of Word application
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

//Open an existing Word document, Make sure the file is exist in this path- otherwise the program fails.
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Scripts\Test.doc")

//Create instance of random object
Set objRandom = CreateObject("System.Random")

intLow = 1
intHigh = 5

//Get the text of word document
Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
//Get the charcters of the text
Set colCharacters = objRange.Characters

 //Set different styles randomly 
For Each strCharacter in colCharacters
    intRandom = objRandom.Next_2(intLow,intHigh)

Select Case intRandom
    Case 1 strCharacter.Font.Name = "Arial"
    Case 2 strCharacter.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    Case 3 strCharacter.Font.Name = "Courier New"
    Case 4 strCharacter.Font.Name = "Forte"
End Select
```

Next

Comment: What's the issue? Does it work with an earlier version of Word but not 2007?

Comment: I don't even know how to script I have read a few scripting articles and tried to plug it in to the VB macro recorder in word but it did not work. I was hoping someone could plug it in to there version of word quickly and get it to work or find a quick solution to what i was doing wrong. I honestly don't even know what kind of script it is. I understand if there is not a quick fix or solution for this then I guess I'm on my own. Thanks for the reply any way.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to the program the following references:

1. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
2. Microsoft Office Object Library

You can do it by right ckick on project -> Add reference, from the GAC tab select the first reference I mentioned above, from the COM tab select the second one.